# get date based on month and year

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

This is very noob question and maybe the answer is hidden in what I am doing here.

In my Extjs project, I am getting dates based on `month` and `year` variables provided by user (slider). By doing the following:

```
var curDate = new Date("Fri " + month + " 15 20:05:44 UTC+0530 " + year);
```

The above code works, but it looks disgusting and even I don't know whether that day is friday or not. Any help to improve the above code?

I tried:

```
var curDate = new Date(year + ", " + month); //no use
```

I tried hard but couldn't find any help online.

**PS**: For those who are interested to know how I am getting the date:

```
Ext.Date.format(curDate,'d');
```

Comment: `var curDate = new Date('1 ' + month + ' ' + year);` is slightly cleaner?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal I think `1` here is date which I don't want to hardcode.

Comment: If you only need the month and year, why are you even bothering using a Date? Why not just `{ month: month, year: year }`?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal sorry I don't know what happened to me. you are right that can be done. `var curDate = new Date('1 ' + month + ' ' + year);`

Comment: Yes, but it's ugly, and probably not the best solution.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal I think this is the best to go with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26700/discussion-between-phenomnomnominal-and-mr-green)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have looked very hard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var d = new Date(year, month0based, day);
```

Comment: Then why not hardcode the day? In your example you're using Friday but how do you know it's Friday if the day is missing?
new Date(year, month9Based,1).getFullYear and .getMonth (I think) to change the zero based month value to string you could use an array: ["January","Frebr...

Comment: Evan, I ask noob questions every day. I am sorry to waste your time.